# SSRS 2019 URL Reservations Configuration AccountName mismatch

Tags: reportserver, ssrs-2019

This might not matter but it struck me as odd and I would like to know if I have a looming issue of one form or another.
**Situation**:  The Service Account set in SSRS Configuration Manager, which matches the account running the service is set to a Domain account.  Under the URL Reservations (for both "ReportServerWebServices" and "ReportServerWebApp") the  tag is set to the default NT Service Account. as in

```
  <Application>
     <Name>ReportServerWebService</Name>
     <VirtualDirectory>ReportServer</VirtualDirectory>
     <URLs>
        <URL>
           <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
           <AccountSid>*a sid number*</AccountSid>
           <AccountName>**NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices**</AccountName>
        </URL>
     </URLs>
  </Application>
```

**SQLServerReportingServices** is not the name of the service account.
Hope this isn't a dumb question but I get nervous about ongoing maintenance when things don't line up.  Also, I have tried resetting the Service Account and the value listed in the example above never changes.